# Connect access point to RPi's ethernet port

Tags: pi-3, ethernet, access-point

I get a public wifi in my living room, which I would like to extend for the rest of my house. I have an Android phone, RPi 3b and Belkin N300 wireless router.

The setup I have in mind is

> Public Wifi <-->Android phone <--> (over USB tethering)Rpi(eth0) <-->
>   Belkin N300 as an access point

. Could someone guide me in the right direction to achieve this setup? 
Here are few guides which I've already looked at: 
https://filippobuletto.github.io/home-router-lte/#configure-the-network
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md

Comment: You asked for a solution to this setup. There is a much more simpler solution only using the RasPi to resolve the problem.

Comment: I was assuming that phone connected to wifi on 5GHz would have better performance than pi's inbuilt wifi